# Calling a child's methods where the defined reference type belongs to parent but the actual reference is a child object

Tags: java, methods

I have a parent, and a child class,

```
class Parent
{
    // variables
    // constructor
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    // variables
    // constructor
    public void AChildMethod()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And inside my program, I have a reference of the main type, but it references to a child type

```
Parent obj = new Child();
```

Is it possible to call the "AChildMethod" method of the child in a way like this?

```
obj.AChildMethod();
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether it really is an instance of the Child class, and then simply cast to the child type:

```
if ( obj instanceof Child ) {
    ((Child) obj).aChildMethod();
    // or
    Child childObj = (Child) obj;
    childObj.aChildMethod();
}
```

However, if a cast like this is needed, it could be an indication that your class hierarchy should be improved.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that `obj` is actually a `Child`, then you can cast it to a `Child` and then call `childMethod`.  That's the only way to do it.